# pandas: substract timedelta in loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily data and  a loop that defines every third Friday in a month and then changes the value of a column to 2 for the 20 days from and to that third Friday. However, the marking only works for the days AFTER the third Friday not before. I do not get it why. 
My dataframe "merged" is the following:

```
Date         ID    Window
01/01/2000   1        0
01/01/2000   1        0
02/01/2000   2        0
02/01/2000   2        0
```

The code so far is the following:

```
#Get third friday in a month Friday:

c = calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)
year = 2000; month = 3
monthcal = c.monthdatescalendar(year,month)
third_friday = [day for week in monthcal for day in week if \
            day.weekday() == calendar.FRIDAY and \
            day.month == month][2]

#Loop through dates to change the window column:

for beg in pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2017-05-01"): 
    beg= third_friday
         merged["window"].loc[beg: beg + pd.to_timedelta(20,"D")] = 2
         merged["window"].loc[beg: beg - pd.to_timedelta(20,"D")] = 2

#repeat the same for the next Fridays:
    if month==12:
       year=year+1
       month=0
    if year>=2017 and month>=3:
       break
    month = month +3
    monthcal = c.monthdatescalendar(year,month)
    third_friday = [day for week in monthcal for day in week if \
                day.weekday() == calendar.FRIDAY and \
                day.month == month][2]
```

When I run this code, I do not get the window column to 2 BEFORE the third Friday. Only the days 20 days after the third Friday are changed to 2. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you do know that these 20 day before and after periods overlap

Comment: But apparently you only do that every 3 months, not every month, so ignore what I said above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Third Friday of the month

easiest would be to define a method to calculate the 3rd friday of the month, given a year and month. Either use your method with `calendar`, or something like this might work too

```
def third_friday_of(year, month):
    pd.DatetimeIndex(start = '%i/%i/15' % (year, month, ), end='%i/%i/21' % (year, month, ), freq='d')
    return daterange[daterange.weekday == 4][0]
```

this returns a `pandas.Timestamp`, but that's a subclass of `datetime.datetime`, so should pose no further problems in your program

## Actual calculations

I also defined a seperate method to do the actual changing of the `DataFrame`, with the interval and window as parameters

```
def process_dataframe(df, begin_year, begin_month, end_year, end_month, interval_months=3, window=20):
    end_month = min(end_month + 1, 12)
    dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(start = '%i/%i' % ( begin_year, begin_month,), end='%i/%i' % (end_year, end_month), freq='%im' % interval_months)
    for d in dates:
        third_friday = third_friday_of(d.year, d.month)
#         print(d, third_friday)
        df.loc[third_friday - pd.Timedelta(window, unit='d') : third_friday 2 pd.Timedelta(window, unit='d'), 'Window'] = 2
```

The reason it might not have worked for you was `merged["window"].loc[beg: beg - pd.to_timedelta(20,"D")] = 2` should have been `merged["window"].loc[beg - pd.to_timedelta(20,"D"):beg] = 2`

## Chained assignment

`merged["window"].loc[beg: beg + pd.to_timedelta(20,"D")] = 2` in itself has a second problem. With `merged["window"]` you ask for a Series, but it's not 100% clear or deterministic whether you get a view or a copy. Better is to do this in 1 `.loc` like in my code